# Rewrite rule in apache httpd-ssl.conf

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to redirect user in following way.

This is part of my snippet from -ssl.conf

```
<virtualhost>
 RewriteEngine on   

 RewriteRule ^/login.html? /

</virtualhost>
```

If the user makes request to `https://mysite.com/login.html` , I want to direct them to `https://mysite.com/`

Either I get a race condition or a 404 with apache log stating

`Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support  apache 2.4`

Comment: What's Apache logging when it sends the 404 response?  Do you want to redirect the user, as in, change the address in their location bar?

Comment: Posted the info from the apache log file. I could go either way as far as changing the url in address bar

Comment: What type of OS/Distro/browser are you using? Note: SNI wouldn't work on windows XP

Comment: Apache24/windows/chrome

Answer (score 0):

There ought to be some "file does not exist" warnings in the logs as well, but no matter.

Try adding a redirect to your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/login\.html? / [R=301]
```

If that doesn't work, then it's likely a problem with virtual host mapping as the log entry is alluding to; provide the output from `apachectl -S`?